# Backbone fetch not working with single model

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

Here is my backbone code:

```
var UserModel=Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: 'http://api.myapi.com/user'
});

var user=new UserModel();
user.set({id:1});
user.fetch();
console.log(user.get('screenname'));
```

This returns the whole collection of users instead of user with the id of 1.  When I change the url to

```
url: 'http://api.myapi.com/user/1'
```

I get back the user that I want.  Why don't I get the record for 'user 1' when I `user.set({id:1});`

***Note*** - My API is at a different domain, that is why I have the entire URL in my `url` property.  Please help, I am ready to give up on backbone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add the id to your model url like so.

```
url: function() {
 if(this.id) {
   return 'http://api.myapi.com/user/' + this.id;
 } 

 return 'http://api.myapi.com/user';
}
```

And then when you instantiate the user model you can pass it an id like this.

```
var user = new UserModel({id: 1});
```

Then when you do `user.fetch()` it will get `'http://api.myapi.com/user/1'`

Also by not passing an `id` to `UserModel` Backbone will send a POST request to  `'http://api.myapi.com/user'`

Comment: Wow, that worked.  Why do I have to do it like that?  I thought fetch was supposed to do that for you?

Comment: Backbone will if you use the urlRoot property.

Comment: That's what I proposed :)

Comment: @RidaBENHAMMANE @KyleNeedham I tried to use urlRoot originally, but it still says it needs a 'url' - `Uncaught Error: A 'url' property or function must be specified`

Answer (score 5):

You have to set the `urlRoot` not `url` and Backbone will add the `id` to the end of your url :

```
var UserModel=Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: 'http://api.myapi.com/user'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two points you need to validate:

1. **Model** use `urlRoot` as rest API url, but **Collection** use `url`.
2. Output result in the `fetch` success callback

   var UserModel=Backbone.Model.extend({
       urlRoot: 'http://api.myapi.com/user'
   });

   var user=new UserModel();
   user.set({id:1});

   //It is safe to output result in success callback which guarantee the api is called
   user.fetch({success: function(){
       console.log(user.get('screenname'));
   }});